# How to avoid external content to affect my page's styling

Tags: html, css

In my application I am loading external markup inside a div on my page. But sometimes the external content messes up the styling of my page.

The application gives a list of user's email from gmail and on clicking on an email it's loaded in the div. But sometimes the email's styling affects the styling of my whole page. Is there a way I can avoid that ?
I don't want to remove all the html tags from external content as I want to keep the original styling of email.

Comment: Use different class names, use an external stylesheet etcetera.

Comment: Run the external content through an HTML parser and apply a whitelisting filter to strip out anything invalid, style related or script related.

Comment: add  !important to the styles that get overridden. e.q. .test { color: black !important }